# If a pointer's address is 64 bits, why does it appear as 6 bytes when printed?

Tags: c, pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void){
  int *ptr;
  printf("the value of ptr is %p",ptr);
}
```

This gives me `0x7fffbd8ce900`, which is only 6 bytes. Should it be 8 bytes (64bit)?

Comment: 0x00007fffdb8ce900

Comment: The value you're printing is garbage, since you don't initialize `ptr`. There's no reason to assume that it contains a valid address.

Answer (score -6, accepted):

Because the 6-bytes address is just the virtual address(offset of the actual physical address). In physical architecture(X86 for instance), memory is divided into portions that may be addressed by a single index register without changing a 16-bit segment selector. In real mode of X86-CPU, a segment is always using 16-bit(2-bytes) segment-selector, which will dynamically decided by the Operating-System at the very beginning when your program started to run(i.e. creating actual running process).

Hence, if your variable have the 48-bit address 0x7fffbd8ce900, and your program have the segment-selector offset 08af, and the real address of the variable is (0x08af<<48)+0x7fffbd8ce900 = 0x08af7fffbd8ce900, which is 64-bit.

further reading pls turn to:
[x86 memory segmentation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_memory_segmentation)

Comment: Wow, your answer open my eye of memory architecture, Is there any way to inspect the content of real memory content like using c or linux command line tools?

Comment: This answer is incorrect.  Modern operating systems use a flat virtual address space without segmentation, and segmentation isn't even supported in 64-bit mode ("long mode").  The 16 bits in question are *not* a place for a segment selector.

Comment: No, this mixes 8086 real mode (where a seg:offset address was mapped to `seg<<4 + offset`) with virtual memory, which doesn't work that way at all. Just totally wrong.

Comment: After carefully checking out the difference between 32-bit and 64-bit architecture, I found out that in the 64-bit architecture, there is no more segment selector structure for addressing, so, really sorry for presenting the incorrect answer. Moreover, really appreciated Wyzard and BoPersson for pointing out my fault and update my knowledge

Answer (score 22):

Although a pointer is 64 bits, [current processors actually only support 48 bits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64#Canonical_form_addresses), so the upper two bytes of an address are always either 0000 or (due to sign-extension) FFFF.

In the future, if 48 bits is no longer enough, new processors can add support for 56-bit or 64-bit virtual addresses, and existing programs will be able to utilize the additional space since they're already using 64-bit pointers.

Comment: I don't understand the part on `they're already using 64-bit pointers` why waste space if it's not gonna be used in the foreseeable future?

Answer (score 6):

That just means the first two bytes are zero (which, incidentally, is currently guaranteed for x86-64 chips—but that doesn't mean anything in this case, since your pointer is not initialized). `%p` is allowed to truncate leading zeroes, just like any other numeric type. `%016p`, however, is not. This should work fine:

```
printf("the value of ptr is %016p", ptr);
```

Comment: What's difference between `printf(.., ptr)` and `printf(.., &ptr)`?

Comment: @Jack Is that related to the question? Passing `ptr` means you'll see the address of the pointer contained in the variable `ptr`. Passing `&ptr` means you'll see the address of the variable `ptr` itself.

Comment: &ptr would give the address of the ptr variable, as opposed to the address of what is being pointed to

Comment: "%016p": The 0 will cause it to be undefined behavior.

Comment: @lord.garbage how? Last time I checked, the zero means to zero-pad the output, instead of the default, which is to use spaces. I use this format all the time to keep the numerical presentation of my numbers consistent.